# jQuery UI Select in combination with the Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select, jquery-validate, drop-down-menu

I want to validate my selectboxes but because i use jQuery UI to style my selectboxes it is not working.

Jquery UI is set the real selectbox on display : none so that is why it not work see:
[image: html]

But how can i make it work with the jQuery UI selectbox plugin?

I hope somewone has a working solution. :)

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? The plugin's attach method hides the original selectbox and replaces it (by using display:none) with custom one. You have to work with selectors provided by the [plugin](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/) instead.

Comment: Hi Izdt, i am not really a JS programmer so i not really understand what you are saying. I hope you can help me? I have made a JSFiddle with the code that i now have: http://jsfiddle.net/jB5mE/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just due to the fact that `selectMenu` hides the `select`. By default, validate does not validate hidden elements. You can change this by setting the `ignore` option to `[]`:

```
$(".valid").validate({
    meta: "validate",
    ignore: [],
    groups: {
        checks: checkbox_names
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr("type") == "checkbox")
            error.insertAfter(element.parent().siblings().last());
        else if (element.is("select")) {
            error.insertAfter(element.next("a.ui-selectmenu"))
        }
        else error.insertAfter(element);
    }
});
```

As you noticed, changing the `selectMenu` does not re-validate the input. You can get around this by tapping into the `change` event on the `selectMenu` and re-validating the element manually:

```
// SELECTBOXES
$(function() {
    $('.dataTables_length input, select').not("select.multiple").selectmenu({
        style: 'dropdown',
        transferClasses: true,
        width: null,
        change: function() {
            $(".valid").validate().element(this);
        }
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8YvSN/

Comment: You are the man, thnx! But when a user select an option then the error message dont disappear, is there a way that it can be done?

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your time.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Huge help for me too. In case anyone like me was too lazy to view the jsfiddle example, the .valid selector in $(".valid").validate().element(this); is referring to the form element: <form action="" class="valid">

Answer (score -1):

```
change: function() {
   $("#validate-form-name").validate().element(this);
};
```

This works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)