# get the selected value of selectmenu jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a form with couple of drodowns that are styles using selectmenu. These drodowns are hidden initially. On certain conditions it will be displayed. So i need to check if the dropdowns are displayed, the user should select a value from that and then only allow him to submit the form.
If the user is not selecting any value, error should be displayed and the form should not be submitted.

JS file for selectmenu

```
if ($.fn.selectmenu) {
  $('select.dd-select').selectmenu({
    style:'dropdown',
    maxHeight: 300,
    transferClasses: true
  });

}
```

JS file for validation

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function(){
var returnValue = true;
$('#form1 .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
inputVal = $(".dd-default option:selected").val();
alert(inputVal); -- displaying null
var input = $(this);alert(input.val()); -- displaying null
input.next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
input.removeClass('required');
if (!input.val()) {
    input.addClass('required');
    var $msg = input.attr('title');
    input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>'); --error message not shown
    returnValue = false;
}

 });
});

$('#form1 .required').change(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    input.next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
    input.removeClass('required');
    alert(input.val());-- displays the value
    if (!input.val()) {
        input.addClass('required');
        var $msg = input.attr('title');
        input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>');-- the error message is also displayed properly
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="dd1" name="dd1" class="required dd-select" title="Please select to continue.">
  <option value=""> --</option>
   <%= List %>
</select>
```

In the above code, if no values are selected, its highlighting but not displaying the error. The error it should take from the title attribute of the select. On change of the value, its alerting the new value. But on submit again the value is displayed as null.
I dont know how to create a fiddle for this with selectmenu. If I create a fiddle only with the dropdown validation, it works fine. I think when its selectmenu, do we have any separate way to get the selected value?
Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong and guide me on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You display the errormessage on  !input.val()  which means, that there is no value or value=0.
Why not alert inside the if (!input.val()) {}

```
        if (!input.val()) {
            alert("Ther is no value!"); // new alert()
            input.addClass('required');
            var $msg = input.attr('title');
            input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>');//-- the error message is also displayed properly
        }
```

Comment: Hi Lisa..!input.val() means if there is no value I need to display error.But even after selecting a value, on submit function, the input.val() is always displaying as null..But on change() function input.val() is correctly displaying value. But when it comes to submit, its displaying null.Any idea why it is behaving like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a library like jquery validation. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026176/jquery-ui-select-in-combination-with-the-validation-plugin) you will find useful information about how to make it work with selectmenu. You can then add customized methods to check if the dropdown is visible or not.